# How to export more images in XML feed from WooCommerce

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Evening, I have a WooCommerce store and I need export my products via xml feed. I have the following working code witch creates an xml feed for my WooCommerce products:

```
foreach ($result as $index => $prod) {


$sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_stock_status';",0);


$stockstatus = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

if ((strcmp($stockstatus[0]->meta_value, "outofstock") == 0)& ($ifoutofstock==1) ){
    continue;
}

$sts = $stockstatus[0]->meta_value;

$sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
    WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE 'onfeed';",0);

$onfeed =$wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (strcmp($onfeed[0]->meta_value, "no") == 0) {
    continue;
}


   $sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE post_id =" . $prod->ID . " AND meta_key LIKE '_price';",0);
    $meta = $wpdb->get_results($sql);


   $sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE post_id =" . $prod->ID . " AND meta_key LIKE '_max_variation_price';",0);
$newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($sql);


 $imagelink = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT `meta_value` FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta  WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND meta_key LIKE '_thumbnail_id' ",0);
    $imagelinkres = $wpdb->get_results($imagelink);


    $images = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT `guid` FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts   WHERE `id` =" . $imagelinkres[0]->meta_value . " AND post_type LIKE 'attachment' AND `post_mime_type` LIKE 'image/%%' ;",0);

    $image = $wpdb->get_results($images);

$skusql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_sku';",0);

$skus = $wpdb->get_results($skusql);


$cat = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships as tr , " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy  as tt
WHERE `object_id` =" . $prod->ID . " and tr.term_taxonomy_id =tt.term_taxonomy_id and tt.taxonomy like 'product_cat'  ",0);


$flag = 0;
$categories = $wpdb->get_results($cat);

$sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE 'mpn';",0);

$mpn = $wpdb->get_results($sql);



$sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
    WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_product_attributes';",0);


$attr = $wpdb->get_results($sql);



if (strcmp($attr[0]->meta_value, "a:0:{}")) {

    $sizestring = "";
    $childs = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT `id` FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts WHERE `post_parent` =" . $prod->ID . " AND post_type LIKE 'product_variation' ;",0);

    $childs = $wpdb->get_results($childs);
    foreach ($childs as $child) {
        $sstock = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE `post_id` = " . $child->id . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_stock';",0);
        $sstock = $wpdb->get_results($sstock);
        if ($sstock[0]->meta_value > 0 || $sstock[0]->meta_value==NULL ) {
            $sizes = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE `post_id` = " . $child->id . " AND `meta_key` LIKE 'attribute_pa_size';",0);
            $attrsize = $wpdb->get_results($sizes);
            $sizename = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *  FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms WHERE `slug` LIKE '" . $attrsize[0]->meta_value . "' ;",0);
            $sizename = $wpdb->get_results($sizename);
            $sizestring = $sizename[0]->name . ", " . $sizestring;
        }
    }
}
$man=null;
$tempid = $prod->ID;

if (strcmp($attr[0]->meta_value, "a:0:{}")) {       

    $manufacturer = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships as tr, " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy as tt , " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms as t WHERE tr.object_id = " . $tempid . " and tt.term_taxonomy_id= tr.term_taxonomy_id and tt.term_id=t.term_id and tt.taxonomy like 'pa_manufacturer'  ;",0);
    $man = $wpdb->get_results($manufacturer);
}

if(count($man) == 0)
{   
$manufacturer = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships as tr, " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy as tt , " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms as t WHERE tr.object_id = " . $tempid . " and tt.term_taxonomy_id= tr.term_taxonomy_id and tt.term_id=t.term_id and tt.taxonomy like 'product_brand'  ;",0);
$man = $wpdb->get_results($manufacturer);
}

$color = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships as tr, " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy as tt , " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms as t WHERE tr.object_id = " . $tempid . " and tt.term_taxonomy_id= tr.term_taxonomy_id and tt.term_id=t.term_id and tt.taxonomy like 'pa_color'  ;",0);
$colorRes = $wpdb->get_results($color);

$last_key = end(array_keys($categories));
foreach ($categories as $index2 => $cat) {

    if ($index2 != $last_key) {
        continue;
    }


    if ($cat->taxonomy == "product_cat") {



        $product = $products->addChild('product');
        $term_que = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
        FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms
        WHERE `term_id` = " . $cat->term_id . "
        ;",0);


        $terms = $wpdb->get_results($term_que);

        $cat_par_id = $cat->parent;
        $category_path = $terms[0]->name;


        while ($cat_par_id != 0) {
            $term_que = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
        FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "terms
        WHERE `term_id` = " . $cat_par_id . "
        ;",0);
            $terms = $wpdb->get_results($term_que);
            $category_path = $terms[0]->name . " > " . $category_path;

            $cat_par = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy  as tt
WHERE   tt.term_id =" . $cat_par_id . " and tt.taxonomy like 'product_cat'  ",0);



            $par_cat2 = $wpdb->get_results($cat_par);

            $cat_par_id = $par_cat2[0]->parent;
        }


        $title = str_replace("'", " ", $prod->post_title);
        $title = str_replace("&", "+", $prod->post_title);
        $title = strip_tags($title);


        $sku = $skus[0];

        if ($sku != "") {

            $id = addslashes($sku->meta_value);
        } else {
            $id = addslashes($prod->ID);
        }
        $product->mpn = NULL;
        $product->mpn->addCData($sku->meta_value);

        $cat_id = addslashes($cat->term_taxonomy_id);
        $price = addslashes($meta[0]->meta_value);
        $fullprice = addslashes($newmeta[0]->meta_value);
        $salespercentage = addslashes($newmeta[0]->meta_value);

        $desc = str_replace("'", " ", $prod->post_excerpt);
        $desc = str_replace("&", "+", $desc);
        $desc = strip_tags($desc);




        $product->addChild('uid', $prod->ID);
        $product->name = NULL;
        $product->name->addCData($title);
        $product->link = NULL;
        $product->link->addCData(get_permalink($prod->ID));


        $product->image = NULL;
        $product->image->addCData($image[0]->guid);

        $product->category = NULL;
        $product->category->addCData($category_path);

        $product->description = NULL;
        $product->description->addCData($desc);

        $product->addChild('category_id', $cat_id);
        $product->addChild('price', $price);
        $product->addChild('fullprice', $fullprice);
        $salespercentage=((round(($fullprice-$price)/$fullprice,2))*100 );
        if($salespercentage == -INF)
        $salespercentage =0;
        $product->addChild('salepercentage', $salespercentage);







        if (strcmp($sts, "instock") == 0) {
            $product->addChild('instock', "Y");
            $product->addChild('availability', $availabilityST);
        } else {
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare(  "SELECT *
    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta
    WHERE `post_id` =" . $prod->ID . " AND `meta_key` LIKE '_backorders';",0);

            $backorder = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if (strcmp($backorder[0]->meta_value, "notify") == 0) {
                $product->addChild('instock', "N");
                $product->addChild('availability', "Upon order");
            }else if (strcmp($backorder[0]->meta_value, "yes") == 0) {
                $product->addChild('instock', "Y");          
                $product->addChild('availability', $availabilityST);
            }   else {
                $product->addChild('instock', "N");
            }
        }



        if (strcmp($attr[0]->meta_value, "a:0:{}")) {

            $product->addChild('size', substr($sizestring, 0, -2));
        }



        $product->manufacturer = NULL;
        $product->manufacturer->addCData($man[0]->name);

            $product->color = NULL;
        $product->color->addCData($colorRes[0]->name);

    }

    $flag = 1;
    }
}
```

the results I get from the above code is the following:

```
<products>
<product>
<mpn>
<![CDATA[ ProductSKU ]]>
</mpn>
<uid>3231</uid>
<name>
<![CDATA[ ProductName ]]>
</name>
<link>
<![CDATA[
ProductURL
]]>
</link>
<image>
<![CDATA[
ImageURL
]]>
</image>
<category>
<![CDATA[ CtaegoryPath ]]>
</category>
<description>
<![CDATA[
ProductDescription
]]>
</description>
<category_id>CategoryID</category_id>
<price>price</price>
<fullprice>fullprice</fullprice>
<salepercentage>productPercentage</salepercentage>
<instock>Y</instock>
<availability>availiability</availability>
<size>40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45</size>
<manufacturer>
<![CDATA[ manufaturer ]]>
</manufacturer>
<color>
<![CDATA[ color ]]>
</color>
</product>
```

I would like to add in the feed my additional images from my product with the following format:

```
    <more_images>
        <another_image_1>url1</another_image_1>
        <another_image_2>url1</another_image_2>
        <another_image_3>url1</another_image_3>
</more_images>
```

is there a way to get the data this way?
I need to get other 3 or more images from my products.